# how to populate an excel cell using multiple =IF function

Tags: excel

I have a column that displays data in each cell.
What i want to do in another column is display certain figures based on the data in the other column
eg:

```
Column W     Column X
-0.5            0
564.3          564.3
5000           >4800
```

If the data in column W is equal or less than 0 i want the number in column X to read zero.
If the data in Column W is greater than 0 but less than 4800 i want the number displayed in Column X to read the same number as in column W, and 
If the data in Column W is greater than 4800 i want the number in Column X to read >4800.
I have `=IF((AND(W222>4800,W222<0)),">4800","0")` working so far to the less than 0 and greater than 4800, just can't get the numbers greater than 0 and less than 4800 to display in column X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
=IF(W222>4800,">4800",MAX(W222,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have the numbers in Column W >4800 displaying >4800 in Column X, and the numbers below 0 in Column W showing 0 in Column X using =IF(W222>4800,">4800",MAX(W222,0)) what i need now is that if a number in Column V is >0 i need the cell in Column X to show "+IVE" but still have the same responses to the =IF calculation above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`=IF((AND(W222>4800,W222<0)),">4800",IF((AND(W222<4800,W222>0)),W222,"0"))`

Comment: Thank you very much, its working for everything but the numbers in column W that are greater than 4800 are now displaying 0 in column X

Comment: That first and is never true. You might want to make it an or, then tinker. Or lose the and altogether and just check >4800 there.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the responses. I have the numbers in Column W >4800 displaying >4800 in Column X, and the numbers below 0  in Column W showing 0 in Column X using =IF(W222>4800,">4800",MAX(W222,0))
what i need now is that if a number in Column V is >0 i need the cell in Column X to show "+IVE" but still have the same responses to the 
=IF calculation above.

Answer (score -2):

Reminding u - "-7" is at "W3", 
[This works for u!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTmki.jpg)